# Effective degrees of freedom of relativistic gases: Intuition for fermion factor 7/8?

Tags: special-relativity, statistical-mechanics, fermions, bosons, degrees-of-freedom

When calculating the number density of a gas of identical massless particles you get the following integral
$$ I_{n,\,\pm} \equiv \int_0^{\infty} \frac{u^2}{e^u\pm1} \,\text{d}u $$
with (+) for fermions and (-) for bosons (see section 4.4 of [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04979)). You then inevitably find that the ratio is simply
$$ \frac{I_{n,+}}{I_{n,-}} = \frac{3}{4}$$

For energy density the numerator picks up an extra power of $u$ because massless particle energy is proportional to momentum (pick c=1):
$$ E(p)\,\text{d}^3p = \sqrt{p^2-m^2} \,4 p^2\,\text{d}p = 4\pi p^3\, \text{dp}$$
and so
$$ I_{\rho,\,\pm} \equiv \int_0^{\infty} \frac{u^3}{e^u\pm1} \,\text{d}u $$
with ratio
$$ \frac{I_{\rho,+}}{I_{\rho,-}} = \frac{7}{8}$$

While this calculation is straight forward, it gives me no intuition for why the number (energy) density of a gas of massless fermions should be $3/4$ ($7/8$) that of massless bosons.

Can anyone think of an intuitive or perhaps geometric explanation for this physical property and integral identity?

[arXiv:1609.04979](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04979)