# Why we multiply the quark contribution term by 7/8 while calculating the degrees of freedom for QGP?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, quark-gluon-plasma

**Why we multiply the quark contribution term by 7/8 while calculating the degrees of freedom for two flavour QGP?**
That is,
g = 7/8 (2×2×2×3) + 2 × 8
Why there is a factor factor of 7/8 ?

Comment: Can you give a reference to clarify what you're asking? Maybe something like equation (2.3) in [`https://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys741/xji/chapter2.pdf`](https://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys741/xji/chapter2.pdf)?

Comment: Depending on what you're asking, the body of this question might give the answer: [Effective degrees of freedom of relativistic gases: Intuition for fermion factor 7/8?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/544645)